# What if the default method / techniques to make a robust multi-person tracker in crowded areas (single fixed camera)?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, tracking

The more I read about the multiple-object literature the more it seems impossible to track objects (in my case, persons walking or running around) without eventually losing them.

When I look at SOTA trackers such as Bytetrack, Centertrack, FairMOT etc, -out out the box- they all seem to forget previously identified objects or mismatch them, both of which cause serious problems.

If I use person re-identification (reid) it adds significant computational overhead.

Maybe, I am not reading the right papers or maybe industrial / commercial trackers use different techniques (post-processing?) that make them more robust to forgetting and mismatch of tracks?

I would appreciate any tips & pointers.

(my use case is indoors & fixed camera, about 20 people in the room, lots of moving around & occlusion)

Answer (score 0):

I evaluate multi-object SOTA trackers as they come out. None of the top 3 solves this problem completely; specially not when objects are entering and exiting the field of view of the camera. I recommend you to train a custom model for the specific environment where it will be deployed to minimize this issue.

Feel free to check out my GitHub repo where [I try all these MOTs out](https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet).